# Simple client/server, TCP/IP encrypting the message stream, SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, client, tcp

Writing a little TCP/IP client server app.  Basically it creates a server, and then you can create several different clients and set up a bit of a chat session.  What I am wondering is there is any way to incorporate, using standard .net libraries some form of encryption?

m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Stream,
                            ProtocolType.Tcp);

Is there any way of speficying tcp using rsa?

Or would you (me that is) have to write some custom libaries to do key exchange and then encrypt the subsequent chat messages?  I have done that before for uni but that was in java but I know it would'nt be hard to convert them.  Just trying not to have to reinvent the wheel...

Or what about utilising a ssl?

Thanks, Ron.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004/how-do-i-add-ssl-to-a-net-application-that-uses-httplistener-it-will-not-be

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to encrypt your communication would be to just wrap the entire socket stream in a [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx).

This is made to work directly with TcpClient/TcpListener, so it's very easy to encrypt a data stream using this.

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like the answer I was looking for.  I will get on this asap.  Thanks, Ron.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it around a library, or alternatively, an SSL tunnel application.