# httplistener and http connect method

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the HTTP Proxy setting on my ipad to redirect traffic to my .net httplistener.
If i send http traffic using the ipad proxy sends the traffic to my httplistener, and
my code does its thing. If i send https traffic using the ipad and its http proxy I see the packets show up at my machine (sniff using wireshark) on port 8443, but my listener doesn't get kicked off. I have the prefixes and certificates correct. I proved this out by instructing a browser to go directly to my machine w/o the http proxy using port 8443.

I noticed from my sniffs of the https connection attempt that the HTTP CONNECT method
is contained in the packet. Its probably trying to tunnel the SSL traffic. Does http.sys or httpListener recognize/handle the CONNECT method ? I am curious why my httplistener isn't firing off ??

thoughts on how I can further troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not stated in your question, so have you actually setup your HttpListener to support SSL with a site certificate as documented in this question?

[How do I add SSL to a .net application that uses httplistener - it will *not* be running on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004/how-do-i-add-ssl-to-a-net-application-that-uses-httplistener-it-will-not-be)