# How to create an HttpListener using https

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl, https

I am design a http server using .NET.
Now, I want to make it as a https server.
I basically use HttpListener to get http request from client.
I know how to create a SSL certificate.
But how can I configure the HttpListener to use that SSL certificate?

Comment: Did you look at the first ["Related" question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004/how-do-i-add-ssl-to-a-net-application-that-uses-httplistener-it-will-not-be?rq=1) on the right?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the https prefix (e.g. https://*:8443). Then bind a certificate to this port.

See answer Walter Kelt:
[The steps to add SSL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support)